# Make photos available only to me on Google+

Tags: google-plus, privacy, google-plus-photos

This may already be the default, I don't know.

I turned on a feature in the Android app Photos and now all my pictures have been uploaded to Google+. The exact website is https://plus.google.com/photos. I'm not very clear on how this works, I thought I was using google drive. How do I make the photos visible to only me? What are the privacy settings? I assume anything on Google+ is by default available to anyone.

Comment: Since this is a question about an Android app, it would probably have been better at [android.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your automatically backed up photos are private unless you choose to share them.

[Back up photos & videos automatically](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1647509)

Comment: Thanks. What I find confusing is that the app I use on my phone is called "Photos" so it didn't occur to me to search the documentation of Google+. In general I find that's a problem with Google products, you're not exactly sure which one you're using e.g. is a document being sent to Google+, Google Drive or emailed to gmail etc. ?